# PHP Calculation - getting relevance score

Tags: php

I have an application that stores data in database. I need search functionality to work on this database.

For this to work I need a "relevance" score, a score that is calculated based on a set of criteria to output as a value that can be then used to order a set of data.

Say for instance the user enters three keywords: X, Y and Z - I need to generate a score based on a database entry. I wish the criteria to be related to how many times each appears.

Example:

Database Entry A - X appears 8 times Y appears once and Z appears once. Giving a collective score of 10.

Database Entry B - X appears 24 times Y does not appear and Z does not appear. Giving a collective score of 24.

Here's my problem. Database Entry A IS more relevant based on the search of XYZ because it has all three database entries, not just one, yet a standard calculation would class Database Entry B as more relevant.

I need to figure out a way to calculate the results and give an number score to the result based on not just how many of each keyword appears, but also giving higher scores for those results that have more than one keyword displayed, exponentially (i.e. entering 10 keywords would show results where all 10 appear above ones with large amounts of one).

I need to achieve this with PHP which will be retrieving my database results and feeding them back to my website page.

Comment: What database engine are you using?  Both Postgres and MySQL can calculate rangings for you when using their fulltext features, and other popular databases probably have this covered as well

Comment: MySQL. If they have this already built in to the database, how would I utilise it? Cheers

Comment: `MATCH (...) AGAINST (...)` computes a relevancy. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could compute two relevance scores. One that rates based on how many fields provided a match, and then your regular "how matches were found". From your examples, that would provide:

```
Example A - field_count: 3, match_count: 10
Example B - field_count: 1, match_count: 24
```

and then have your query do

```
ORDER BY field_count, match_count
```

so that matches with more fields get sorted first.

Comment: wow, that seems so simple. Thanks for the lateral thinking :)

Answer (score 0):

Since the (first) presence of a keyword is so important, give it a better score than the rest of the occurrences. For example:

```
$score = 0;
foreach ($keywords as $count) {
  $score += $count==0 ? 0 : 1000000;
  $score += $count;
}
```

If you apply this algorithm to your example, you will have:

```
Entry1 ---> (1000000 + 8) + (1000000 + 1) + (1000000 + 1) = 3000010
Entry2 ---> (1000000 + 24) = 1000024
```

So Entry1 scores better than Entry2 as you wanted.